# Double bookmark in pdf file

Tags: environments, bookmarks

I got a small problem with my LaTeX document.
I generate a list of listings like this:

```
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Quellenverzeichnis}
\lstlistoflistings
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Quellenverzeichnis}
```

This generates the correct page and adds a correct link to the toc.
However in the pdfs bookmarks there are two links to `Quellenverzeichnis`, one pointing to the page before it and one pointing to the actual page.
I already tried to use `\renewcommand*` without any difference.

PS: I am using MiKTeX through TeXnicCenter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a document class like `scrbook` the macro `\lstlistoflistings` is able to create an entry in the toc.

Your line `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Quellenverzeichnis}`  adds the second entry to the toc (comment it).

You didn't say it, but I guess, the first bookmark points to the page before.

A simple `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` (depends if you print one- or doublesided) should correct this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Quellenverzeichnis}
...
\begin{document}
... % here something happens causing the need of next line
\cleardoublepage
\lstlistoflistings
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Quellenverzeichnis}  %<===== you can delete this line! 
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. You werer right, the first entry was pointing to side before. The cleardoublepage resolved this issue, but I still got 2 entries in the pdf bookmarks (ToC was and is correct). Both entries now point to the correct page

Comment: EDIT: Have to revoke the 'Perfect' ;) While this removes the unwanted bookmark, it also removes the entry from the toc. I think something in the class file went astray. I will try to sort things out.